# How Write Java Configuration for this XML configuration.?

Tags: java, xml, spring, spring-java-config

I am in the middle of converting my appconfig.xml tp JavaConfigurations(AnnotationConfigs). I did converting most of the beans into JavaConfig. But I am got stuck with couple of beans which are listed below. Could some one help me on this..??

**1.The Bean has a list element which takes values from a properties file..
The XML Configuration is :**

```
<bean id="propertyCommons"
        class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
        <property name="locations">
            <list>
                <value>classpath:dbUser.properties</value>
            </list>
        </property>
        <property name="ignoreUnresolvablePlaceholders" value="true" />
    </bean>
```

How do we convert this to java Config..(especially taking values from **dbUser.properties**?

**2.How do we convert the following factory configuration to JavaConfigs?**

```
    .
    .
    .
    <bean id="oozieJobFactoryBean" class="com.mycompany.product.dfe.main.OozieJobFactoryBean" />

    <bean id="cmdArgs" class="com.mycompany.product.dfe.main.CmdArgs"
            scope="prototype" />

    <bean id="oozieJob" factory-bean="oozieJobFactoryBean"
            factory-method="createJob" scope="prototype">
            <constructor-arg ref="cmdArgs" />
    </bean>
    .
    .
    .
```

**3. Also the following Configuration ..**

```
.
.
.
<bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
        <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactory" />
</bean>

<bean id="entityManagerFactory"
    class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
    <property name="persistenceUnitName" value="productPU" />
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
    <property name="jpaVendorAdapter">
        <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter" />
    </property>
    <property name="jpaPropertyMap">
        <map>
            <entry key="hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache" value="true" />
            <entry key="hibernate.cache.use_query_cache" value="true" />
            <entry key="hibernate.cache.provider_class" value="net.sf.ehcache.hibernate.SingletonEhCacheProvider" />
            <entry key="hibernate.show_sql" value="false" />
            <entry key="hibernate.format_sql" value="false" />
            <entry key="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect" />
            <entry key="javax.persistence.validation.mode" value="NONE" />
            <entry key="hibernate.connection.characterEncoding" value="utf8" />
        </map>
    </property>
</bean>
.
.
.
```

Please help me on this am new to spring.. :)
Thanks in Advance...

Noushad Ali.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer

```
@Configuration
@PropertySource(value = "spring/test5.properties")
class Config {
    @Bean
    PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer propertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer() {
        PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer c = new PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer();
        c.setIgnoreUnresolvablePlaceholders(true);
        return c;
    }

...
```

2. OOzieJobFactory

   class Config {

   ```
   @Bean
   @Scope("prototype")
   CmdArgs cmdArgs() {
       return new CmdArgs();
   }

   @Bean
   @Scope("prototype")
   OozieJobFactory oozieJobFactory() {
       return new OozieJobFactory();
   }

   @Bean
   OozieJob oozieJob(OozieJobFactory factory, CmdArgs cmdArgs) {
       return factory.createJob(cmdArgs);
   }
   ```

   }
3. EntityManager

   class Config {

   ```
   @Bean
   LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean localContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean() {
       LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean b = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
       b.setPersistenceUnitName("productPU");
       ...
       return b;
   }

   @Bean
   JpaTransactionManager jpaTransactionManager(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean emf) {
       JpaTransactionManager tm = new JpaTransactionManager();
       tm.setEntityManagerFactory(emf);
       return tm;
   }
   ```

Comment: Thanks @Evgeniy Dorofeev, Can you help me on my second and third question..?

Comment: Phew, code in enumerated lists *really* is getting ugly. I remember a Meta question about how to fix this.

Comment: I think it is tm.setEntityManagerFactory(emf.getObject());